# cant get String.valueOf(int) method to work

Tags: java, bluej

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqu0T.png)

i am trying to convert an int to a string, and i want this string to be returned. the error it gives says "incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int" any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: what is return type of the method, check if its int

Comment: yeah it was type int not string. thank you so much

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, but post code as text in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with your return type of method.
Your method may look like below where return type is int.

```
public int intToStringConverter(int i) {
String v=String.valueOf(i);
return v;
}
```

Actually it should be like below:

```
public String intToStringConverter(int i) {
String v=String.valueOf(i);
return v;
}
```

Comment: yes that worked. thank you so much